# exporting the experiment/simulation screen with PLE possible?

Tags: export, anylogic

so i made the model for my thesis and like to share it with my prof. over the anylogic cloud. Unfortunatelly when i try to export the model it shows:

**"Model parameter values overridden by experiment 'Simulation' will not be used; default values will be exported."**

and it will not show the simulation screen in the cloud version. Is this because i use the PLE, if no: how can i improve my export?

i already tried the documentation and various google searches, but i was not able to find anything useful.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simulation screen in the cloud. This is independent of your version.

Learn how to create simulation-setups in the cloud by checking the "Run configuration" part of your model before uploading to the cloud. Also check the help on that and example models (those uploaded by AnyLogic to the cloud and that you find matched in the AnyLogic example library).

[image]